# bash: get the directory argument

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script that uses calling syntax

script [options] [dir]

To retrieve the set of options and parse them I use getopts. But how can I get the dir argument? In general, if I retrieve the last argument as ${@:${#@}}, it does not have to be the dir, it can be still an option or a value of it.

Code I use for getopts:

```
DIR="."
RECURSIVE=
FILTER=
while getopts “hnf:” OPTION
do
case $OPTION in
    h)
        usage
        exit 1
        ;;
    n)
        RECURSIVE="-maxdepth 1"
        ;;
    f)
        FILTER=$OPTARG
        ;;
    \?)
         exit 1
         ;;
    :)
         exit 1
         ;;
esac
done
```

Can you help?

Comment: If `getops` does not leave you with only non-option arguments left to handle, you are not using it correctly. Show us your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OPTIND` stores the position of the processed parameter. After the loop do a:

```
shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

Now the directories are in `$@`, first directory is in `$1`.

Comment: What should I do if the script should take arguments also in reverse order, `script [dir] [options]`

Comment: And the best way to distinguish between the two? I use a test, if the first argument begins with "-", then it is the version [options] [dir], otherwise it is [dir] [options]

But it feels kinda dirty, not the way these things should be done

Comment: theoretically a directory name could start with a dash... there's a reason all unix commands start with the options. supporting both directions seems a very bad idea to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
DIR=
RECURSIVE=
FILTER=
while getopts ':hnf:' OPTION ;do
  case $OPTION in
    h)  usage; exit 1 ;;
    n)  RECURSIVE="-maxdepth 1" ;;
    f)  FILTER=$OPTARG ;;
    *)  echo "ERROR: invalid opion: -$OPTARG" 1>&2; exit 1 ;;
  esac
done
# remove the options from the positional parameters
shift $((OPTIND-1))
DIR="$1"
echo "FILTER=$FILTER"
echo "DIR=$DIR"
```

Example command-line

```
script -n -f 'my.*filter' 'my/directory'
```

Example output

```
FILTER=my.*filter
DIR=my/directory
```